# move data of Document Library from on Site to sub site in Office 365 Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a Task to move data of Document Library from on Site to sub site, below is the situation,
Using office 365
Need to migrate a library and its folder to a sub site where folders would be treated as libraries in that sub site
The size of the library is 3.29 GB.
I have to write a custom code for this.
The various details of the documents etc must be restored like the modification date, version history etc.

Comment: What is the question?
Of course you need write custom code for this task or use 3rd party components from sharegate, metalogix or something else.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't copy over version history. 'Move' functionality still works better but quite tedious. Is there a 'Move-PnPFolder' powershell command that can make this process more automated?

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the Document Library as template including its content:

> 1. Go to the library you would like to migrate, click LIBRARY in the upper left corner> click Library Settings.
> 2. Click Save document library as template > type in the File name and the Template name > select "Include Content" > click OK. Then the template has been saved to List Template Gallery.
> 3. Go to the destination site, click Site Contents > click add an app.
> 4. In the search box, type in the name of the template you have created to create a new library. The newly created library is the same as the one in another site.

Reference: [SharePoint Online - Migrate document library](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/238266.aspx)

[image]

[image]

Comment: This absolutely should not have been so hard to find, especially considering it was clearly built to be simple.

Comment: @leigero SharePoint isn’t always obvious :)